# How to make gap between elements equal

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I need item 1, item 2 (top items) and side item to be the same size with same space between them. Bottom item needs to be under top items and be as wide as the top items combined.

https://codepen.io/ermek-barmashew/pen/PowZoKO?editors=1100

```css
.content {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: calc(100% * 2/3);
    background-color: gray;

}


.top-item {
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

.bottom-item {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow
}

.side-item {
    background-color: #7c7d98;
    width: calc(100%/3 - 20px);    
}
```

```html
<div class = 'content'>
  <div class = 'container'>
      <div class="top-item">
        Top item 1
      </div>

      <div class="top-item">
        Top item 2
      </div>

      <div class="bottom-item">   
        Bottom item
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="side-item">
  Side item
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you alter the HTML? Can you use CSS Grid?

Comment: I can alter html, but only flexbox is allowed. I feel like I'm missing something about the calc.

Comment: If you can only use flexbox (grid would be better, but okay), then you'll have to define precise lengths between elements. Don't use `justify-content` because that only distributes free space, which can vary between screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

RESULT
[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">      
  <div class="right-items">
    <div class="top-item1">
      Top Item 1
    </div>

    <div class="top-item2">
      Top Item 2
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-item">
      Bottom Item
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="space">
  </div>

  <div class="side-item">
    Side Item
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
/* Root */
.container {
  display: flex;
}


/* Right Side */
.right-items {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

 /* Space in the center */
.space {
  width: 2%;
}

/* Left Side */
.side-item {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Right Items */
.top-item1 {
  width: 50%;
}

.top-item2 {
  width: 50%;
}

/* Left Item */
.bottom-item {
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

**DEMO**

https://codepen.io/wilsonbalderrama/pen/VwYaLrR